# Facebook Graph API taggable_friends giving invalid scope ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm building a simple webapp that collects the users friends and photos. Using omniauth-facebook to connect with the Graph API.

However, when I give taggable_friends as one of the auth scopes, I get the following error that is displayed in the Facebook login dialogbox.

```
Invalid Scope: taggable_friends
```

This is my `omniauth.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['facebook_app_id'], ENV['facebook_app_secret'], :scope =>'public_profile,user_photos,taggable_friends,user_friends', :display => 'popup'
end
```

I'm able to successfully authenticate the user with `user_photos` scope which also requires review from Facebook. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: And be aware that you will only be able to use taggable_friends to tag friends. Nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permission required for the `<user_id>/taggable_friends` enpdpoint is `user_friends`. There is no `taggable_friends` *permission*, only the *endpoint*.

You can read more on it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends?locale=en_GB#readperms